# A virtual method of a parent class has its own implementation body block?

Tags: c#, virtual-functions

Question of C# programming language.

Question: "A virtual method of a parent class has its own implementation body block".
My answer: "false".

Is my answer correct? If it is not, please explain me, guys.

Comment: It can have its own implementation but you can overwrite it

Comment: Please read the help center. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: why not do some research and check out the c# spec? specifically, section 1.6.6.4

Comment: Only way it doesn't have an implementation is if it's `abstract`.

Answer (score 1):

No, your answer is, in the general case, incorrect.

In c# there are two(*) ways to declare a virtual method:

```
virtual Foo Method1()
```

Or

```
abstract Foo Method2()
```

In the first case, it is mandatory that the method has its own implementation body block (or its own expression-bodied function member). In the second it's the contrary, it's mandatory that it doesn't. The former *may* be overridden in derived classes, the latter *must* be overridden in non abstract derived classes. Last, but not least, the great majority of virtual methods are of the former form.

(*) purists might argue that interface members are also virtual methods (virtual final to be exact) but I'll ignore the issue as it doesn't change the answer.